# google maps javascript api not working on multiple connections

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have created a page which uses google maps API v3. The problem I am facing is that it works perfectly on my WiFi connection but whenever I try to run it using a different WiFi connection then it doesn't work and console also doesn't have any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your cookies and try again. Maybe you need to add an api key.

Comment: API key is already there in the code. Will try the clear cookies method.